# Why must I have images in my code to make it work

Tags: php, wordpress, post, meta

I have this code:

```
    <meta name="description" content="<?php
    $page_object = get_queried_object();
    $page_id = get_queried_object_id();
    $the_query = new WP_Query("p=".$page_id);
    if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
            $content = substr(strip_tags(get_the_content()),0,155);
            echo esc_attr($content);
        endwhile;
    }
?>" />
```

It echoes the first 155 characters of the content of a blog post which it does inside the content of a description tag. This works if the content has an image inside of it but results in nothing it the post has no image in the content. I use:

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
```

In my functions.php. Does anybody know why I have to have an image in my post for this to work?

Comment: Is it possible that you have broken HTML tags in your post? If so, strip_tags can remove a lot more than you intended.

Comment: As an aside, why do you rerun wp_query instead of just using `$content = substr(strip_tags(get_queried_object()->post_content),0,155)`?

Comment: I just wrote a new blogpost without an image and the description worked. It seems that its only the posts written before I removed wpautop that also has no image that has the problem and that's just 2 posts. So this isn't a big problem anymor :)